# angularjs module, which name to use? and why?

Tags: angularjs

I have two question for the below codes:  I just learn `angularjs` and find it is very confusing:

1. factory.quote and QuoteFactory. Why can't I use the factory.quote name in the controller?
2. why can't I put the 'ngResource' inside like   angular.module('factory.quote',[]).factory( 'QuoteFactory', ['ngResource','$resource', function ($resource)

   ```
   (function () {
   'use strict';
   angular.module('app', [
   // Angular modules 
   'ngRoute',
   'controller.quote',
   // Custom modules 
   'factory.quote'


   // 3rd Party Modules

   ]);

   angular.module('controller.quote', []).controller('QuoteController', ['$scope', 'QuoteFactory', function ($scope, QuoteFactory) {
   $scope.quote = QuoteFactory.query();
    }]);

   /*angular.module('controller.quote', []).controller('QuoteController', ['$scope', 'factory.quote', function ($scope, factory.quote) {
   $scope.quote = factory.quote.query();
   }]);*/

   angular.module('factory.quote',['ngResource']).factory('QuoteFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
   return $resource('/api/quote', {}, {
       query: { method:'GET',param: {},isArray:true}
   });
    }])
     })();
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the angular paradigm for the web applications from  medium to large size goes in this way

We have a separate folder fro controllers , services/factories , directives , constants , filters and so on...

actually when creating any module we do as
angular.module('your-module-name',['dependent modules']);

So while creating controllers ,

we say your-module-name.controller('your-controller-name',['dependent factory/service modules'])
so that the controller acts as the client side logic implement(r) and communicates to the services where the factory function have the
http calls to the server side code

So in your case
**factory.quote and QuoteFactory. Why can't I use the factory.quote name in the controller?**

As discussed above in my post ,

usually we communicate to the service/factory functions which inturn talk to server side code through http calls or any other protocols
So **we need the factory/service modules**   to help us with their functions  so that we can communicate to the server side code

hope this is clear

and coming to your second question

**ngResource** is the name of the module  which provides the services/functions which can be used with their names
**but to use the functions of the ngResource (which is a module)**
**we need to import it in our main module**

that is why we put it in [] i.e dependecies list of our angular module

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you are creating separate modules for `controllers` and `factory`.

**1) Why can't I use the factory.quote name in the controller?**

`factory.quote` is your module name and it contains any number of controllers and factories. In this controller, you have created a single factory only in the code it's name is `QuoteFactory`. You are going to user this factory in your controller not the module. So, you can't you your module name here, you must use factories name which are inside tyour module `factory.quote`.

**2) why can't I put the 'ngResource' inside like angular.module('factory.quote',[]).factory('ngResource' ,'QuoteFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource)**

`angular.module('factory.quote',[]).factory('ngResource' ,'QuoteFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource)` - What are you doing here? Are you trying to create a factory with name `ngResource`? This code is totally confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) factory.quote and QuoteFactory. Why can't I use the factory.quote name in the controller?

- `'factory.quote'` : is a **module name**. The usage is when you got another module (e.g. `'app'`) want to use what is available in `'factory.qoute'`

```js
// Here you are telling 'app' to load module 'factory.qoute'
angular.module('app', ['factory.qoute'])
```

- `'QuoteFactory'` is a **factory name** which is available **inside** `'factory.qoute'` module.

```js
// Here you are telling 'app' to load module 'factory.qoute'
angular.module('app', ['factory.qoute'])
// Here you are using 'QuoteFactory' which is the content of 'factory.qoute'. 
.controller('QuoteController', ['$scope', 'QuoteFactory', function ($scope, QuoteFactory) {
    $scope.quote = QuoteFactory.query();
}]);
```

=> In fact '**factory.qoute**' and '**QuoteFactory**' those are name of 2 difference thing. It is like a machine named **factory.qoute** has a mechanism named **QuoteFactory**.

It is like you have a keyboard. And when you want to use `[Enter]` button. You don't plug the `[Enter]` button into your PC. But you will need to plug a whole keyboard into your PC.

> 2.) why can't I put the 'ngResource' inside like angular.module('factory.quote',[]).factory('ngResource' ,'QuoteFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource)

Similar answer for first question. `'ngResource'` is a module, you don't use it at layer of mechanism.

It is like: You don't plug your keyboard into your monitor but in your PC.

Comment: I think I got it, first create a module then create the service/controller.  To use it, you must load the module then use the service.